# How can i respond with JSON with a Lambda function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lambda

Below I am trying to repond to a GET with the weather in JSON format.  I am attempting the use the const done in order to deliver the response.  This does not seem to work.  I get the response and weather in console but return nothing to the client.

```
'use strict';

 console.log('Loading function');
 const doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
 const http = require('http');
 const dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();

 function get_json(url, callback) {
   http.get(url, function(res) {
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        var response = JSON.parse(body);
        callback(response);
      });
    });
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {


const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
    statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
    body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});

switch (event.httpMethod) {
    case 'DELETE':
        dynamo.deleteItem(JSON.parse(event.body), done)
        break;
    case 'GET':
       // dynamo.scan({ TableName: event.queryStringParameters.TableName }, done);
        done(get_json("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=92f14e06a6652e81a5a58bd13d152f70", callback,  function (resp) {
        callback(resp);
         })); 
        break;
}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_json()` doesn't return anything, so passing it into `done` is definitely the wrong thing to do.

It looks like you need to do this:

```
get_json(
   "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=92f14e06a6652e81a5a58bd13d152f70", 
    resp => done(null, resp)
);
```

Comment: That's just amazing.  Thank you very much